# Why program works correctly while join only 1 thread but there are 5

Tags: c++, multithreading

This is my code and I accidentally made a mistake buy not making the for loop longer but the code works as intended.

What happens after the program is completed? Does it have any fail cases or does the computer auto kill all thread and if there would be any additional code it Threads again would there be problems( for example if i would initiate 2 thread then there would be 6 thread working and the new thread ids would be 5 and 7?)

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

bool endProgram = false;

struct Monitorius {
public:
    int IOCounter = 0;
    int readCounterC = 0;
    int readCounterD = 0;
    condition_variable cv;
    mutex mtx;
    int c = 10;
    int d = 100;

    Monitorius() {
        c = 10;
        d = 100;
        IOCounter = 0;
        readCounterC = 0;
        readCounterD = 0;
    }

    void changeC(int i) {
        while (!endProgram) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
            cv.wait(lck, [&] {return readCounterC > 1; });
            if (!endProgram) {
                c += i;
                readCounterC = 0;
                cv.notify_all();
            }

        }
    }
    void changeD(int i) {
        while (!endProgram) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
            cv.wait(lck, [&] {return readCounterD > 1; });
            if (!endProgram) {
                d -= i;
                readCounterD = 0;
                cv.notify_all();
            }
        }
    }
    void readCD(int i) {
        int oldC = -1;
        int oldD = -1;
        while (!endProgram) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
            cv.wait(lck, [&] {return oldC != c && oldD != d; });
            if (!endProgram) {
                stringstream str;
                str << i << ": c:" << c << " d: " << d << endl;
                cout << str.str();
                readCounterC++;
                readCounterD++;
                IOCounter++;
                if (IOCounter >= 15)
                    endProgram = true;
                cv.notify_all();
                oldC = c;
                oldD = d;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Monitorius M;
    vector<thread> myThreads;

    myThreads.reserve(5);

    myThreads.emplace_back([&] { M.changeC(1); });
    myThreads.emplace_back([&] { M.changeD(2); });
    myThreads.emplace_back([&] { M.readCD(3); });
    myThreads.emplace_back([&] { M.readCD(4); });
    myThreads.emplace_back([&] { M.readCD(5); });

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        myThreads[i].join();

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The OP says they know what the issue is, they are curious as to why it still works, and what happens to the threads that weren't joined

Comment: @OP What compiler are you using?

Comment: "... does the computer auto kill all thread  ..." - That's somewhat OS specific. On Linux (and other Unix like OSs) when the main thread exits the entire process is destroyed (including any other threads). On Windows threads can keep running after the main thread exits. I can't remember what happens with Novell NetWare and other niche OSs.

Comment: @NathanOliver  I am running this code on visual studio 2017(windows 10) as a console application, not sure how to specify the compiler.

Comment: @ArminasPamakštis That's fine.  It's interesting that you say it works for you.  Unless it takes a while to run it looks like when I run it I get in an infinite loop and the program never actually finishes.

Comment: Just because a program ends does not mean it has worked correctly. You can look at the exit status of the application. Im this case your code will have exited via `std::terminate()`, not from exiting `main()` this should result in an error code being returned to the OS. If you are on Linux like OS. Try `echo $?` this will tell you the exit code of the last application run. A non zero value means something went wrong.

Comment: @NathanOliver you are correct, now that i take a closer look at the console it never gets to the _getch part... but even after increasing the join number it still doesnt work so most likely the thread that read are asleep and never wake up.

Comment: You code has two other bugs. One is that your `cv.wait` calls don't check `endProgram` as part of the predicate. So they will keep waiting even if the program should end. Another is that some of your checks of `endProgram` (such as the `while (!endProgram)` check) don't take place under the protection of any mutex so there is no way you can ever set `endProgram` to true because you have no way to ensure it's not being accessed at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your `main` function exits, all the threads in the vector will be destructed.

If they are not joined at that time `std::terminate` should be called by the [`std::thread` destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).

---

By detaching threads the thread-objects can be destructed and the thread still continues to run. But then on the common modern operating systems when the process ends (which happens after `main` have returned or `exit` is called) the threads will be killed anyway. To let threads continue running even after the "main" thread ends, you have to call a system-dependent function to exit the "main" thread.

I do not know if it's possible to do this on Windows though, as [the `ExitThread` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitthread) should not be used by C++ code as it exits the thread without destructing objects.

---

The solution to both problems is of course to properly join all threads.